# AS3: bringing an object to front each frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a UI object that, of course, should always be kept in front of all other objects. To do that, I decided to destroy and add it again each frame, like this:

```
removeChild(UI_Indicator)
addChild(UI_Indicator)
```

But nevertheless, objects that are created in it’s area still come on top of it. How is this even possible? I also tried the common

```
UI_Indicator.parent.setChildIndex(UI_Indicator,UI_Indicator.parent.numChildren - 1)
```

But it doesn’t work too. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not destroying anything with `removeChild()`, you just stop displaying it. `removeChild()` isn't even necessary here. `addChild()` happily takes a `DisplayObject` that is already a child of the `DisplayObjectContainer` you called it on and re-adds the child again (to the top)

1. Instead of doing this re`addChild()`ing every frame, place your
   allways-on-top `DisplayObject` on the display list once, then create
   a `DisplayObjectContainer`, say a `Sprite` for example and add it
   behind your indicator. Now add all your other `DisplayObjects` to
   that container. This has the disadvantage of requiring you to add
   everything to the container. The functionality breaks as soon as you
   accidentally `addChild()` the regular way. This thought process
   leads to the second solution below.
2. In your subclass of `DisplayObjectContainer` that includes the
   indicator, override the methods that interact with the display list
   (add/remove children, etc.) All those that could cause something to
   get on top of your indicator. This puts you in full control of
   what's going on when something is added to this container. You can
   either incorporate solution 1 for simplicity's sake: delegate all
   method calls to the inner container `Sprite` or, if you don't like
   to have an internal container, do it without it and make sure that
   no other child than your indicator is ever assigned the top most
   index. You'd create an additional method to add the always-on-top child, like `addTopChild()` for example.

Comment: Well, considering that the project is half-done, looks like there's no easy way of doing it. Thanks for advice, I'll give both options a go if the first one doesn't work out.

Comment: @Yarick use the second option then. It allows you to keep your existing code as is while adding the always-on-top functionality.

Comment: I don't have much experience with overriding methods yet so I tried looking for an easier option once more - and succeeded. I simply created an empty MC and stored all the stuff that was able to get on top of UI elements there. It worked perfectly. Nevertheless, things you suggested were added to my "to learn" list :)

Comment: @YarickShokopets so you picked option 1, nothing wrong with that. Glad you found a solution. As you have a working solution now, I highly recommend at least giving option 2 a try. Stating to not have experience with something doesn't gain you any experience.